# CiviCRM Membership Status Change Summary Report

Tags: civireport

What is the best way to use CiviReports to show how many members changed from grace -> expired in a given month (summary), not detail report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a Membership changes Status an Activity of type "Change Membership Status" is created, and for your example, has the Subject of "Status changed from Grace to Expired". These factors can be used either in Find Activities, or Report civicrm/report/instance/3, or in Drupal to make a View, and if we use Aggregation, to get summary statistics as requested in the question.

I decided to give the latter a Proof of Concept and have attached it. IF this is useful to you (or anyone) please consider 'giving back' (and forward) by chipping in to our project to get CiviCRM working fully with Drupal 8 ;-) http://www.fuzion.co.nz/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=4.

Hmm can't see how to attach file so have put in the Fuzion Treasure Chest at http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/getting-summary-stats-membership-status-changes-view

And in order to fully answer the question, if you use the Views CiviCRM Dashlet module described here you should be able to set it up on your dashboard https://civicrm.org/blogs/brandonferrell/drupal-views-civicrm-dashlets

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you something slightly off topic? Wouldn't it be cool if the Dashboard used Panels / or a layout builder so we could make "Custom Reports" with it, which are summaries/views/totals from elsewhere (Dashlets / Views)? Then we could save these. In my experience using CiviCRM people have to piece together a few reports to get the data they need.

Comment: I think piecing together will always be required since everyone's needs are different. unless i misunderstood your point. If you mean using Drupal Panels, well CiviCRM is multi-CMS and even lots of the Drupal versions would probably not be using Panels. I have been wondering about pulling together a batch of Drupal Views as a starting point for Drupal users to get some Reports that civi may not yet do as easily, but the real solution is to contribute back custom Reports for CiviCRM to include imo.

Comment: I think it would be great if we could customize the layout of the Dashboard at the bare minimum with a "Panels like interface" (add regions / rows / columns as needed) so I could take various Civi Dashlets / Drupal Views-as-Dashlets and place them there, to make a custom "Dashboard". Then, one could save Dashboards and there would be a tab at the top or something to switch between them, to consolidate views of different things. Food for thought for myself mostly.

Answer (score 1):

Membership Summary report doesn't provide the information you're looking for out of the box.  Is there a reason that using the Membership Detail report or Activity report and just using the "Statistics" section at the bottom doesn't meet your needs?

If you're committed to this path, you can write a custom report based on the existing Membership Detail or Activity report that doesn't show any results, just the "Statistics" section.

Comment: I want to use the Dashboard in CiviCRM like a dynamic "report builder" and have reports produce "statistic field dashlets" so my org can get the data it needs really quick upon logging into CiviCRM. Any tips on how to make a custom report with just the statistics section? Would be nicer if any user in Civi could make this, "just show statistics" feature.