# Membership Status Report

Tags: civimember

I have done a CiviCRM installation for a local networking club.  They are adopting CiviCRM slowly, and at the moment we only have the member's contact records and membership records imported.

We need a report that shows the number of memberships that are of different statuses; they want to know at any given time how many current members, grace members, expired members, etc.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a 'count' for each status, ie a small table showing eg
Member Type X, Status A 12
Member Type Y, Status A 5
Member Type X, Status B 15 etc

and if you are using Drupal, then I built a View to demo how you can do this which you can download from [here](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/getting-summary-stats-membership-status-changes-view)

NOTE: you may need log in as user/1 (or Masquerade as admin) in order to access the Import View window.

NOTE: this was done in response to the [stackexchange question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3475/civicrm-membership-status-change-summary-report)

Comment: Not using Drupal on this one. Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

By "any given time", do you mean you want to be able to pick any historical date and see how many members you had in each given status? If so, that's not doable out of the box. You can get basic total member numbers by searching on start/end dates, but this won't catch people in 'New' or 'Grace' periods etc.

Afaik most CRMs struggle with this idea of looking at data from a particular point in time. It's a regular question I get, and tbh I never have a good answer. For what it's worth we just use an script which dumps member numbers to a csv once a day.

Comment: Good point, but I should have said "current", i.e., any particular day, look and see membership status totals.

Comment: if you are after 'point in time' ie how many Grace on date X, it was also discussed http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/is-it-possible-to-get-point-in-time-membership-data

Answer (score 0):

Steps are:

1. Go to Reports >> Membership Reports >> Membership Details
2. Then on Filter tab choose "Member Since" of desired date range and "Membership Status" of your choice.
3. Preview Report and in order to save a copy of the Report click "Save a copy" and change the title of your new report copy

That's it

Comment: Tried it.  Nope.

1) This report seems to be tied to contributions.  As I said above, this organization isn't there yet.  I only have contacts and memberships to work with.  Payment for the memberships is done externally for the moment.  Only one membership shows on this report, and it happens to be a member that I demonstrated making a manual contribution record with.  This report isn't functional without contributions.

2) This is a detail report and doesn't provide counts.  There is no option to group by Status, either in the Grouping tab or Sorting/Group By header.

Comment: Member Since is a moving target (probably a bug) where the Member Since value can change on the currently or most recently active membership and default to the date of the start of that particular membership record.